# Alternative to running external programs in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

In attempting to run an external program in Powershell, the only way I have been able to get this particular line to run is with `[Diagnostics.Process]::Start()`. However, this does not seem to work in older OSes, like Windows XP. Is there another alternative? I have attempted an Ampersand (&) type of run, but it jacks up my arguments. Here's what I have:

```
$vmrc = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\VMware\VMware Remote Console Plug-in\vmware-vmrc.exe"
$vmrcArgs = "-h $($server) -p $($unencoded) -M $($moref)"

[void] [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($vmrc, $vmrcArgs)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start-Process should also work.

```
$vmrc = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\VMware\VMware Remote Console Plug-in\vmware-vmrc.exe"  
Start-Process -FilePath $vmrc -ArgumentList "-h $($server) -p $($unencoded) -M $($moref)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck using invoke-expression to run Robocopy, for example, with loads of command line parameters.

```
$cmd = "$vmrc$vmrcArgs"
$out = invoke-expression $cmd
```

Comment: I started out with Invoke-Expression but there is a character limit that is a problem for me. My $unencoded string is really long. Good answer though, just in case anyone else comes looking.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this little C program useful in determining what PowerShell does to arguments passed to an external program.  (Compile it for UNICODE.)

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", GetCommandLineW());

    for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        wprintf(L"arg[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It your original example, it might have worked if you had invoked the command as:

```
& $vmrc -h $($server) -p $unencoded -M $moref
```

I say "might" because I don't know what is in $unencoded and $moref.

Trying to invoke it as:

```
& $vrmr $vmrcArgs
```

would have resulted in the value of $vmrcArgs being enclosed in quotes in the command line to the external app so the app would likely interpret it as a single argument.  Play around with the C program some and you'll see how PowerShell tries to make intellegent decisions on quoting things when it generates the command line for the external app.

(If your intention was to run a detached process then this answer is inappropriate.  Sorry if that is the case.)

Comment: Definitely want it as a separate process, but this is a good answer none the less.

Comment: By "detached process" I meant that PowerShell would not wait for it to complete before prompting for the next command.  All external programs run in a separate process whether they are detached or not.

Comment: right, I gotcha. In this particular case, the executable needs to run, but free up my powershell session for continued command execution. (ie run them parallel.)